# why rospy time always prining zero?

Tags: ros, gazebo, python, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need a time while running the simulation, but in my code returns zero time.

print rospy.get_time();  #output 0

print rospy.Time.now();  #output 0.0

but i see the time in  terminal when i run   **rostopic echo /clock**

Am i doing anything wrong while reading time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237248/why-rospy-time-always-prining-zero?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you initialize the ros node?

> rospy.init_node("mynodename")

The typical approach to get the current time is:

> now = rospy.Time.now()

If you are using some kind of simulation you also have to take into account how the use_sim_time parameter influence to the behavior of the rospy.Time. Have a look to: http://wiki.ros.org/Clock

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-16**:
yes, node was already initialized. still same issue

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-06-16**:
May be the use_sim_time param set to true?
can you check what you get from the following command line:
`rosparam get /use_sim_time`

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-16**:
Yes, the simulation is running.  And the command  **rosparam get /use_sim_tim**e  is giving output **true**.

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-16**:
rospy.Time.now() is working now after setting the use_sim_true param to false in launch file.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-06-16**:
if this answer solved  your question, please mark it as solved.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-03-07**:
Why setting that to false would help? And how do you set it to false?